# display resume to user in txt format

Tags: asp.net

I have Stored my resume(word document) in my database.and i just want to show that resume in txt format to user. how can i show it to user?

Comment: please, provide more information. How exactly do you store it? What database do you use? What do you mean by "txt" format? Do you want to create a file or you just mean, that it's to be viewed as a text? I can guess, that you can just SELECT it from your table and show in a textbox or in an other control.

Comment: Im using upload control to upload my resume in sql server 2005 database and i want to display that resume to user in one screen

Comment: @Domnic, What type of column do you use? varchar? 
and what do you mean by "in one screen?"? Do you want to show your resume on your page or in a file?

Comment: yes i want to show page in a file

Comment: im using Varbinary as a datatype for store my resume in database

Comment: Check the answer, I'm not sure, if it's what you want, but try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that good in ASP.NET, but check the links below. Maybe it's not a solution, you want, but can be useful.

[Save-Read-Image-Database](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Save-Read-Image-Database.aspx)

There isn't that much of difference, depending on what type to you use for your resume, a varchar or maybe varbinary.

[How to Create a text file in ASP .NET](http://aspalliance.com/152)

[Reading and Writing Text Files with the .NET Framework](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145952/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072303-1.aspx)

Tutorials on how to read/write a file in asp.net.

Good Luck!

**UPDATE:**
So if it's a varbinary type, you can read as it was shown in first link. I'll paste a part with some changes.

```
connection.Open();
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("select <resume_content> from <resume_table> where id = @id", connection);
SqlParameter myparam = command1.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
myparam.Value = <your_value>
byte[] resume = (byte[])command1.ExecuteScalar();
MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
str.Write(resume, 0, resume.Length);
```

After that, just save the Stream to a file. Here's the link

[Save a Stream to a File](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4669/save-a-stream-to-a-file/)

**UPDATE 2:**

It's because you SELECT two columns. It takes FileName as the value for byte[]. For two columns you'd need to use ExecuteReader instead of ExecuteScalar.

Check this link

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4278/using-adonet-with-sql-server/2/

Comment: SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=192.163.20.05;uid=sa;Password=abc123/;Database=TEJAASJOB");
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Filename, FileContent FROM tblFiles WHERE username = @username", connection);
            SqlParameter myparam = command1.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            myparam.Value = Session["USER"];
            byte[] resume = (byte[])command1.ExecuteScalar();
            MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
            str.Write(resume, 0, resume.Length);

Comment: im using above query in asp.net page load  but i got error like

Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

Comment: so i want position to display the resume to user how can i declared?

Comment: Check the update 2. and here's the link on difference between execute methods http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2007/05/01/3049.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to direct the user to download the document directly, and they can open it themselves.